# What are the pro's and con's between Yabai and Amethyst window manager

Tags: macos, windows, window-manager

I already have BetterSnapTools, but it lacks some features which I liked on my old Windows laptop (I had AquaSnap installed, which actually has a lot of great features which I miss on the Mac).

Recently I heard about "Yabai" and "Amethyst" which are more "techy" to install and use, but seem to have more in-depth features. So far, I couldn't find any comparison of them at all, so I thought I'd ask this more "general" question and it would be great if we can collect the pros and cons.

I will update this question with relevant information.

Answer (score 6):

Yabai's wiki has a [comparison table of yabai and amethyst](https://github.com/koekeishiya/yabai/wiki#comparison-with-other-window-managers).

[image: yabai vs. amethyst]

However, they do consider this table incomplete and ask for [contributions to the wiki](https://github.com/koekeishiya/yabai/discussions/5) to make it a good comparison table.